# How to optimise an arbitrary function with TensorFlow/Keras?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have some black box simulation code that runs some physics, possibly in other languages, possibly using NumPy. All of it is wrapped and is callable as a Python method:

```py
def fn(x: np.array) -> np.array:
    ... black box ...
    return output
```

Additionally, I have some code that computes the partial derivatives out the output w.r.t. the input `x`:

```py
def gradient_fn(x: np.array) -> np.array:
    ... black box ...
    return grad
```

I would like to optimise the first function using some of the algorithms in Keras/TensorFlow (e.g. ADAM, SGD, etc.). I tried working with the TensorFlow documentation, but I can't seem to do the appropriate approach.

```py
@tf.custom_gradient
def fn_tf_wrapped(x):
    value = tf.numpy_function(fn, [x], tf.float64)
    def grad(upstream):
        return upstream * tf.numpy_function(gradient_fn, [x], tf.float64)
    return value, grad


with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    # Forward pass.
    tape.watch(x0)
    output = custom_fn(x0)

# Get gradients of loss wrt the weights.
gradients = tape.gradient(output, x0)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)

optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, x0))
```

However, this just gives me:

```
AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute '_in_graph_mode'
```

Would anyone have any helpful pointers?

Comment: Is everything in `fn` differentiable? Why not just implement `fn` with tensorflow?

Comment: Everything is differentiable, but using adjoint states that are not easily automatically differentiated. There's bunch of heavy lifting on the math side before any code is written. Practically, it can not be completely implemented in TF.